# Use Cookie for SQL where clause

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio using c# Does anyone know how to use a cookie from one page in a SQL WHERE clause on another page. I am trying to pull information from a database in grid form depending on certain values in certain columns. People search cinema listing from the page that stores the cookie. As in select from movies where [FilmName] = "CookieValue".

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [FilmName], [Date], [Time], [Bookings] 
FROM [CinemaListings]";
```

Cookie I want to use in where clause form another page that directs to page with code shown above

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Response.Cookies["SelectedConty"].Value = CountyDrop.SelectedItem.Text;  \    
  Response.Cookies["SelectedFilm"].Value = FilmDrop.SelectedItem.Text; 
  Response.Cookies["SelectedCinema"].Value = CinemaDrop.SelectedItem.Text; 
  //Response.Write(Response.Cookies["SelectedConty"].Value); 
  Response.Redirect("CinemaListings2.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you state what the exact issue is? Is the cookie not placed? Is it empty? You don't know how to retrieve its value? You don't know how to add a parameter to your selectcommand?

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the select statement, pull the values out of the cookie and then build select with these values.

```
var filmName = Request.Cookies["SelectedFilm"];
...

var connection = new SqlConnection(connection string);
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FilmName, Date, Time, Bookings FROM CinemaListings WHERE FilmName = @filmName", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filmName", filmName);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```